# Чтобы при увеличении масштаба экрана, блоки не съезжали, можно ли каждому блоку задавать значение position: absolute?

Tags: css

правильно ли это? Просто я устал искать решение, как закрепить тот или иной блок, чтобы при увлечении он не съезжал

Comment: блоки можно организовать в контейнер, чтобы не съезжали.

Comment: Вероятно, стоит попробовать вёрстку в процентах или vw и vh, либо комбинированную: width: calc(20px + 1vw);

Answer (score 0):

Для этого используют адаптивную вёрстку , медиа запросы.

Так же модно использовать bootstrap , fundation и т д - это css фреймворки которые позволяют быстро масштабировать ваш сайт практически под любые устройства и любые размеры экранов!

По сути на ваш вопрос однозначно ответить не возможно так как ваш вопрос носит начальный уровень.

Рекомендую посетить https://webref.ru и изучить основы css и если что то у вас не будет получаться то уже обращаться сюда с конкретным вопросом.

Так же много познавательного видео на youtube.com по данной тематики.
Разумеется что всё облегчит вам **ментор** это человек который учит но его услуги стоят денег